# Opencv Python: Get coordinates for two different coloured objects

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, threshold, hsv

I am trying to get the coordinates for two different coloured objects using opencv. I have researched it and come up with this code, but I am confused as to how to put bounding boxes, or get coordinates for the two largest objects of the two colours:
[tracking multiple objects by color OpenCV 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892615/tracking-multiple-objects-by-color-opencv-2-x)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

# Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

# Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    lower_green = np.array([50, 50, 120])
    upper_green = np.array([70, 255, 255]) 
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green) # I have the Green threshold image.

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask = blue_mask + green_mask

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have been working with single colored objects from the code here:
http://frozenideasfromthenorth.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/autonomous-flight-of-crazyflie-with.html
This shows you how to put a bounding box around the largest coloured object. I tried adding the masks together in the original code but that just creates a bounding box around any of the coloured objects. I would like to know how to do this for two seperately coloured ones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking two different colors using OpenCV 2.3 and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152504/tracking-two-different-colors-using-opencv-2-3-and-python)

Comment: I had a look at this but places hundreds of bounding boxes around anything of those colours, I want to know how to do it with only the two biggest objects.

Comment: You could, for each color, sort your contours and then use the biggest contour, i.e. `cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]`.  This will give you the 5 largest contours to do what you like with.